# What function does に serve in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> **仕事に**真面目で広大な都市の中をしょっちゅう飛び回っているため、彼女とは連絡を取ろうとしてもそう簡単には捕まらない。

I'm not sure how to interpret the first part of the sentence. What does に do here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

仕事に modifies the na-adjective 真面目 right after it.

仕事に真面目で ≒ 仕事に対して真面目で ≒ "(She is) serious about her job, and ..."

You can say it's not very common, but we can find examples like "料理に真面目で" or [this company slogan](http://securityhouse-soko.net/mind) on the net.